# Quadrotor Target-Tracking Flight Pattern

Tags: image-processing, automation, robotics

I'm programming a quadrotor helicopter drone to chase a moving ground target automatically using image processing. The hardware I'm working with is pretty limited, so in order to make my automatic commands account for the drone's velocity (it doesn't know when it's moving) I have to manually track my target's relative position over time (which can be roughly translated into the drone's movement).

So here's what I have in that regard:

```
int lastX = Targets_Last_Position_Xcoord();
int lastY = Targets_Last_Position_Ycoord();
int nowX = Targets_Current_Position_Xcoord();
int nowY = Targets_Current_Position_Ycoord();

int speedModX = (float)(60 - (abs(lastX)-abs(nowX))) / 60.0f; // Image dimension is 120
int speedModY = (float)(73 - (abs(lastY)-abs(nowY))) / 73.0f; // Other dimension is 146

changePitch(((nowX - 60)/60.0f)*(1 + speedModX));
changeRoll(((nowY - 73)/73.0f)*(1 + speedModY));
```

The function "changePitch" and the others like it cause the next command sent to the drone to include a Pitch change of the specified percentage of the preset maximum tilt. So, I'm telling the drone to tilt an amount directly related to the target's distance from the center of the screen; then I'm throwing in a multiplier based on where the target moved (the distance between the target's last spot and its current spot).

This is my intention anyways; this code only seems to be helping a little bit, and other factors such as air flow and mechanical imbalance (it isn't the most high-quality equipment out there) may be interfering, leaving me to simply see what I want to see.

Is the method I'm using to account for the drone's velocity correct, and/or is there a better way to handle this?

EDIT: calculation of speedModX and speedModY was changed, previous form had unwanted results under some circumstances. New formula correctly creates a modifier based on the difference between the target's previous distance from the origin and the target's current distance from the origin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't figure out a better way of modeling the system, you may want to look into tuning a [proportional–integral–derivative (PID) controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller) for this. They're a general solution used in automation for dealing with feedback loops.

Per the Wikipedia article:

> A PID controller calculates an "error" value as the difference between a measured process variable and a desired setpoint. The controller attempts to minimize the error by adjusting the process control inputs
>   ...
>   In the absence of knowledge of the underlying process, a PID
>   controller is the best controller.

Comment: I've started down this path, and it is very obvious now that PID is not only a solution to my issue here, but something that covers some important aspects of any autonomous control method. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is a reasonably challenging problem, and it's not likely that you'll find a good solution with *ad hoc* control rules.  In the robotics literature, the problem is expressed as a target-tracking one (Google "target tracking robot motion planning" for some interesting reading.)

I've implemented target-tracking for a ground-based, wheeled robot, and I think the methods would apply to your problem.  Furthermore, I think they will scale well to the added 3rd dimension of motion in your problem.  Take a look at implementing "potential fields".  This method models the robot, targets, and/or obstacles as particles with electric charges.  Targets exhibit attractive forces; obstacles are modeled with repulsive forces.  This model is easy to implement and works surprisingly well for simple tracking / avoidance tasks.

[Here](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~pstone/Courses/395Tfall05/resources/week9b-ben-potential-fields.ppt) is a set of slides that introduces the topic. [Here](http://users.isr.ist.utl.pt/~mir/pub/ObstacleAvoidance.pdf) is a pretty good paper on using potential fields for obstacle avoidance.  It shouldn't be much of a task to apply those methods to a tracking problem (just invert the signs!).  Last, [here](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1465439) is a an ACM paper in which the author describe solving a similar target-tracking problem. (I don't have access to the PDF, sorry).

Answer (score 1):

So, what you're doing in the above code is a Proportional controller. You may want to add the Integral and Derivative part if you stick with a PID controller. Also depending on the precision and accuracy of your sensors you'll want to consider a filter to smooth out your values. Start with a simple moving average and go up to a Kalman Filter (you'll learn a lot).

Here's another good reference for your work:
STABILIZATION AND CONTROL OF A QUAD-ROTOR MICRO-UAV USING VISION SENSORS
http://contentdm.lib.byu.edu/ETD/image/etd2375.pdf

Another interesting reference:
http://www.ludep.com/